# JTable ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, abstracttablemodel

For some reason this was removed.
This question is CLOSED and i won't be reading it as i have moved onwards and implemented more methods working. So no need putting snarky comments here, i won't read them.

Ok, so this might be quite the simple question, but here goes. I am setting up a JTable for editing and i want column 1 to have a comboBox editor. I looked up how to do it and followed the instructions which lead me to the code under, however it doesn't seem to actually update into the display. What am I misssing here? Thank you in advance.

```
//MainWindow class
public class MainWindow extends JFrame{
GridBagConstraints gbc;
JTable gridDisplay;
private AbstractTableModel tableModel;
JLabel statusBar;

MainWindow()
{
    super("LayoutEditor");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    gridDisplay = new JTable();
    tableModel = new MyTableModel();
    gridDisplay.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    gridDisplay.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    gridDisplay.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    gridDisplay.setModel(tableModel);


    TableColumn tc = gridDisplay.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>();
    cb.addItem("JLabel");
    cb.addItem("JButton");
    cb.addItem("JTextField");
    cb.addItem("JTextArea");
    cb.addItem("JCheckBox");
    cb.addItem("JList");
    cb.addItem("JComboBox");
    cb.addItem("JSpinnerList");
    cb.addItem("JSpinnerNumber");
    cb.setSelectedIndex(0);
    tc.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(cb));
    MyDataModel temp= new MyDataModel();
    MyTableModel table = (MyTableModel)gridDisplay.getModel();
    table.append(temp);




    JScrollPane gridScroll = new JScrollPane(gridDisplay);
    mainPanel.add(toolBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(gridScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(mb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(1280,720);
    setVisible(true);
    }
]

//myTableModel class
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
ArrayList<MyDataModel> data;
String[] names;

MyTableModel()
{

    names = new String[]{"Type","Variable name","Text","Row","Column","Rows","Columns","Fill","Anchor"};
    data = new ArrayList<MyDataModel>();



}
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            data.get(rowIndex).setType(aValue.toString());
        case 1:
            data.get(rowIndex).setName(aValue.toString());
        case 2:
            data.get(rowIndex).setText(aValue.toString());
        case 3:
            data.get(rowIndex).setRow((int)aValue);
        case 4:
            data.get(rowIndex).setColumn((int)aValue);
        case 5:
            data.get(rowIndex).setRows((int)aValue);
        case 6:
            data.get(rowIndex).setColumns((int)aValue);
        case 7:
            data.get(rowIndex).setFill((int)aValue);
        case 8:
            data.get(rowIndex).setAnchor((int)aValue);
    }

    fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex){
        case 0:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getType();
        case 1:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getName();
        case 2:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getText();
        case 3:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getRow();
        case 4:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getColumn();
        case 5:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getRows();
        case 6:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getColumns();
        case 7:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getFill();
        case 8:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getAnchor();
    }
return null;
}

public void append(MyDataModel item)
{
    data.add(item);
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return names[column];
}
}


//MyDataModel Class
public class MyDataModel {
String type, name, text;
int row, column, rows, columns, fill, anchor;

MyDataModel()
{
    type = new String("");
    name = new String("");
    text = new String("");
    row = 0;
    column = 0;
    rows = 0;
    columns = 0;
    fill = 0;
    anchor = 0;
}

public MyDataModel(MyDataModel test) {
    type = test.getType();
    name = test.getName();
    text = test.getText();
    row = test.getRow();
    column = test.getColumn();
    rows = test.getRows();
    columns = test.getColumns();
    fill = test.getFill();
    anchor = test.getAnchor();
}

public int getAnchor() {
    return anchor;
}

public void setAnchor(int anchor) {
    this.anchor = anchor;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public int getRow() {
    return row;
}

public void setRow(int row) {
    this.row = row;
}

public int getColumn() {
    return column;
}

public void setColumn(int column) {
    this.column = column;
}

public int getRows() {
    return rows;
}

public void setRows(int rows) {
    this.rows = rows;
}

public int getColumns() {
    return columns;
}

public void setColumns(int columns) {
    this.columns = columns;
}

public int getFill() {
    return fill;
}

public void setFill(int fill) {
    this.fill = fill;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
}
```

Comment: Please consider expanding on this code a little bit so that it complies with the [mcve] standard -- that is a small completely independent runnable program. Please check out the link for the details on what we need.

Comment: sure. give me 2 seconds

Comment: Ok, its updated with everything you should need to run the program

Comment: @user2604079, code doesn't compile and there is no main() method so it won't run. You still haven't implement hovercraft's suggestions. I suggest you start with the

Answer (score 3):

> it doesn't seem to actually update into the display.

The value you select from the combo box is not being saved in the TableModel.

Your TableModel needs to implement the `setValueAt(...)` method.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Create a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for a simple implementation. It also shows you what `fireXXX(...)` method to invoke so the table is notified of the change in data.

Comment: is that it? oh man now i feel stupid. ill definitively check that out. Thank you.

Comment: It still doesn't actually add the comboBox to the table.  http://puu.sh/kq9s4/d95d367803.png.  Do i need to fire something after i set the cell editor? I also edited the code to reflect the new setValue.

Comment: @user2604079: because the column is still not editable. 1+

Comment: @user2604079: you don't understand --  The JComboBox only shows up if the cell is editable, and for this to occur you need to override `public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)` and have it return true if the column is 0, something you've not done in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a bit from your model including `setValueAt(...)`, `isCellEditable(...)`, and you forgot to call `fireTableRowsInserted(...)` inside of your append method.

e.g.,

```
    public void append(MyDataModel item) {
        data.add(item);

        // !! don't forget this!!
        int firstRow = getRowCount() - 1;
        int lastRow = firstRow;
        fireTableRowsInserted(firstRow, lastRow);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return names[column];
    }

    @Override //!!
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 0; // allow editing of first column
    }

    @Override //!!
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 0) {
            MyDataModel row = data.get(rowIndex);
            row.setType(aValue.toString());
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
            return;
        }
        super.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
```

You will want to re-read the [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) because you're skipping a lot of key concepts.

And I forgot -- you also need to override `public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)` and have it return true, at least for the JComboBox column, else you'll never see combo boxes since it is an editor.